# Locked out of sudoers file [OSX] ("<user> is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.")

Tags: permissions, osx, sudo

I accidentally messed up my sudoers file earlier and started getting the following error:

```
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 1 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 1
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I tried to do what this post told me to: https://astrails.com/blog/2009/09/29/how-to-fix-a-hosed-etc-sudoers-file-on-mac-osx

I ran `vim /etc/sudoers`, and saw a blank file with only two curly brackets there, like so:

`{
}
~
~
~
~`

I tried to comment out the curly braces, saved the file (despite "read-only" warnings), exited, and ran sudo visudo, which gave me this error:

`john is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.`

It seems I've been locked out of sudo.  Is there any way this can still be fixed?  I'm on a 2017 mac running Mojave 10.14.4.  I know I shouldn't have messed with the file but just got curious...

Comment: "I saved the file (despite "read-only" warnings), exited, and ran sudo visudo...", If you can **save** the file, then why don't you **edit** and save it?

Comment: I'm just worried that I'll mess anything up even more -- I don't know what the original sudoers file should look like / contain. It seems my user got removed from the sudo users, and I'm not sure how to add myself back.

The method I used to edit after encountering the syntax error is from the post I linked above: I vim'd into my sudoers file by going into the finder and setting the administrators group on the file to "Read and write".

Comment: For clarification, this is what I'm doing, and that's the content of my sudo file currently: https://imgur.com/a/16r5YYI

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/424173/334516

Comment: Should I copy that file into my sudoers file using vim?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

I did copy the clean sudoers file to my corrupted one, as @muru recommended, and it worked. I used the following file (I was told it was shipped in the original OSX): paste.md-5.net/fipapovuye.shell I was able to navigate to the file in my finder --> click "get info" (file properties) --> add a user to the permissions tab on the bottom and give the user read+write perms.  I then used vim to copy-paste the content, and saved the file.